# MVC PagedList Dynamic Page/Page Size determined by model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, pagination, pagedlist

I am using the PagedList.mvc helper to handle the paging of my application, in all examples i have found people tend to explicitly set the page size. I wish to set the page size dynamically from data in a model as well create new pages from the data as well.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X3ZF.png)

I have the table stipulated in the image above, i would like it that page 1 is all entries that have the MonthInt as 1 and page 2 all entries as MonthInt 2 etc.. however i want each page size to be determined by how many entries there are for each month.. it currently dynamically sets the sizes of the pages according to the first page and only limits the first page to display entries with the MonthInt 1-3, after that it goes to the next page but doesnt follow the same rule.. Any help/suggestions would be great,

Controller Code:

```
// GET: Customers/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id, string sortOrder, string searchString, string currentFilter, int? page)
    {
        Customer customer = db.Customers.Find(id);

        var viewModel = new CustomerViewModel();


        if (id != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<Vehicle> vehicles = db.Vehicles.Where(c => c.CustomerId == customer.Id);
            List<Vehicle> vehiclesList = vehicles.OrderBy(m => m.MonthId).ThenBy(r => r.Register).ToList();

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
            int pageSize = vehicles.Count(m => m.MonthId <= 3);
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                vehiclesList = vehicles.Where(r => r.Register.Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                                   || r.License.Contains(searchString.ToUpper())).ToList();
            }

            PagedList<Vehicle> pagedList = new PagedList<Vehicle>(vehiclesList, pageNumber,pageSize);

            viewModel = new CustomerViewModel()
            {
                Vehicles = pagedList,
                Customer = customer
            };
        }

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        if (customer == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

View Code:

```
@model Application.ViewModels.CustomerViewModel
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Fleet Details";
 }

 <div>
      <h2>@Model.Customer.Name</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Customers", FormMethod.Get))
{

    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <div class="btn-toolbar">
                @Html.TextBox("searchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, null, new {@class = "form-control", placeholder = "Find by Register/License", autofocus = "autofocus"})
                <input class="btn-warning btn" type="submit" value="search"/>
            </div>               
        </div>
    </div>
}
<hr />
@if (!Model.Vehicles.Any())
{
    <p>No Vehicles loaded</p>
    <br />
}
else
{
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayName("Owner")</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayName("License")</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayName("Make")</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayName("Register")</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayName("MonthInt")</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayName("Month")</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Vehicles)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OwnerName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.License)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Make)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Register)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MonthId)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MonthName)</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-toolbar">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Vehicles", new { id = item.VehicleId }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Vehicles", new { id = item.VehicleId }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Vehicles", new { id = item.VehicleId }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
<div class="btn-toolbar">
    @Html.ActionLink("Add Vehicle", "Create", "Vehicles", new { id = Model.Customer.Id }, new { @class = "btn-success btn" })
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit Customer Name", "Edit", new { id = Model.Customer.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete Customer", "Delete", new { id = Model.Customer.Id }, new { @class = "btn-danger btn" })
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn-default btn" })
</div>
<br/>
Page @(Model.Vehicles.PageCount < Model.Vehicles.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.Vehicles.PageNumber) of @Model.Vehicles.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Vehicles, page => Url.Action("Details", 
    new { page, pageSize = @Model.Vehicles.PageSize }))
Showing @Model.Vehicles.FirstItemOnPage to @Model.Vehicles.LastItemOnPage
of @Model.Vehicles.TotalItemCount Vehicles
```

Example: [Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIw79.png)
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNDTB.png)

Comment: Your defeating the whole purpose of using server side paging by using `.ToList()` in your query. There is no point using the `PagedList` plugin in your case. Just pass a value to the method for the `MonthId` and query your data based on that value (and include for each `MonthId` in the view)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I'm filtering the data that the table shows all entries in descending order by MonthId, so essentially the table is sorted from January to December, thus new entries are placed in their respected groups of MonthId's. The search filtering works as well, however what i would like to achieve is that if the data only had one January and ten February items it would filter the January item to page one and the February items to page two regardless of the amount of items. Basically binding the MonthId to a new page. I'll update my view code to full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution kind of just happened while trying other things. Current solution allows for each month to be on its own page. It might not be the best solution but it works.

Added custom class to group data:

```
public class Group<T, TK>
{
    public TK Key;
    public IEnumerable<T> Values;
}
```

Updated ViewModel:

```
public PagedList<Group<Vehicle, string>> VehiclesGroup { get; set; }
```

Updated Details Controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id, string searchString, string currentFilter, int? page, int? item)
    {
        var customer = db.Customers.Find(id);

        if (customer == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var vehicles = from f in db.Vehicles
                       where f.CustomerId == customer.Id
                       select f;

        var vehiclesList = vehicles.OrderBy(m => m.MonthId).ThenBy(r => r.Register).ToList();

        var groupedVehicles = from v in vehiclesList
                              group v by v.MonthName
                              into g
                              select new Group<Vehicle, string> { Key = g.Key, Values = g };


        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

        var pageSize = vehicles.Count(v => v.MonthId <= 0);
        if (pageSize == 0)
        {
            pageSize = 1;
        }
        var pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            vehicles = vehicles.Where(r => r.Register.Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                           || r.License.Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                           || r.Make.Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                           || r.OwnerName.Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                           || r.Vin.Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                           || r.MonthName.Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
            vehiclesList = vehicles.ToList();
            groupedVehicles = from v in vehiclesList
                              group v by v.MonthName
                              into g
                              select new Group<Vehicle, string> { Key = g.Key, Values = g };
        }

        var pagedList = new PagedList<Group<Vehicle, string>>(groupedVehicles, pageNumber, pageSize);

        var viewModel = new CustomerVehicleViewModel()
        {
            VehiclesGroup = pagedList,
            Customer = customer
        };

        return View(viewModel);

    }
```

Updated View:

```
@model Application.ViewModels.CustomerVehicleViewModel
@using PagedList.Mvc
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Fleet Details";

if (TempData["Error"] != null)
{
    ViewBag.Error = TempData["Error"];

}

}

    <h2>@Model.Customer.Name</h2>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 1%">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Customers", FormMethod.Get))
                    {
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
                                @Html.TextBox("searchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, null, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Search", autofocus = "autofocus", style = "margin-right:1%" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <input class="btn-warning btn" type="submit" value="search" />
                                @Html.ActionLink("Reset", null, null, null, new { @class = "btn btn-info", style = "margin-left: 5%" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="btn-toolbar">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Add Vehicle", "Create", "Vehicles", new { id = Model.Customer.Id }, new { @class = "btn-success btn" })
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit Customer", "Edit", new { id = Model.Customer.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete Customer", "Delete", new { id = Model.Customer.Id }, new { @class = "btn-danger btn" })
                        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn-default btn" })
                        @Html.ActionLink("BRN/ID", "ViewFile", "Customers", new { cid = Model.Customer.Id, id = Model.Customer.FileId }, new { @class = "btn-info btn", target = "_blank" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessage("", $"{ViewBag.Error}", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <hr />
    @if (!Model.VehiclesGroup.Any())
    {
        <p>No Vehicles loaded</p>
        <br />
    }
    else
    {
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayName("Owner")</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayName("License")</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayName("Make")</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayName("Register")</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayName("VIN")</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayName("Month")</th>
                    <th class="remove">
                        <button id="btnPrint" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true"></span> Print Table</button>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.VehiclesGroup)
                {
                    foreach (var i in item.Values)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.OwnerName)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.License)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.Make)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.Register)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.Vin)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.MonthName)</td>
                            <td class="remove">
                                <div class="btn-toolbar">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Vehicles", new { id = i.VehicleId }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Vehicles", new { id = i.VehicleId }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Vehicles", new { id = i.VehicleId }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Scan", "ViewFile", "Vehicles", new { cId = i.CustomerId, id = i.VehicleId }, new { @class = "btn btn-info", target = "_blank" })
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    }
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">@item.Key</td>
                        <td colspan="3"></td>
                    </tr>

                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
    <br />
        Page @(Model.VehiclesGroup.PageCount < Model.VehiclesGroup.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.VehiclesGroup.PageNumber) of @Model.VehiclesGroup.PageCount

        @Html.PagedListPager(Model.VehiclesGroup, page => Url.Action("Details",
                                                new
                                                {
                                                    page,
                                                    currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter,
                                                    pageSize = @Model.VehiclesGroup.PageSize
                                                }))

       Total of @Model.VehiclesGroup.TotalItemCount Pages
```

Updated Display of month January/page 1
[Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXFJO.png)

Updated Display of month February/page 2
[Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C6zG.png)

Updated Display of Page 3
[Page 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXgPY.png)

Hope it helps someone, or if anyone has better ideas please share!